# FFMPEG binaries throw error : Undefined Symbols for Architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ffmpeg, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1

I have created a cocoa app that uses FFMPEG libraries for streaming.

Uptill now i was using FFMPEG version 3.1.1 and i had libraries available to me. Now i downloaded the latest FFMPEG version 3.1.4.

I executed the shell script and libraries were generated but when i use the with my xcode [6.1 or any] I get error as shown in attached image.

Can anybody plz guide me about solving this issue.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

Other Linker Flags :

[image]

Comment: "Other Linker Flags" : Not added : "-Wsuggest-override"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added Frameworks :

AudioToolBox.framework and VideoToolBox.framework

How i understood : Undefined symbol for architecture x86_64 : **A** referenced from **B** in **xyz.o**

Add **xyz.framework**

and its Done :)